# "LNK1104 Cannot open file 'kernel32.lib' " when Windows SDK version is set to 15063.13

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm doing C++ in Visual Studio 2017, and just recently updated Windows 10 from Anniversary Update to Creator's Update.

I found out by accident that when I'm compiling a DLL project, I would get the error message:

`LNK1104 - cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'`

After twiddling a bit in the Project Properties, I noticed if the Windows SDK version is set from `10.0.14393.0` to `10.0.15063.0`, the error message appears. If I set it back to `10.0.14393.0`, I can compile just fine.

I would like to know why when the Windows SDK version is set to the Creator's Update build version, it's throwing this error message, yet it doesn't if set back to the Anniversary Update's build version?

Thanks.

Comment: repair/reinstall Win10 SDK 15063: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41913/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-in-empty-c-project.html

> The Windows 10 Creators Update SDK made some significant changes to
>   what is installed as part of the installation to minimize on-disk
>   footprint. This is a Known Issue that results from that refactoring
>   work where the "desktop" components of the Creators Update SDK do not
>   get installed by default. The previous new project logic always
>   selected the latest Windows 10 SDK, assuming the desktop portions were
>   installed as part of that installation scenario. We are working on a
>   fix for a future update.
>
> The workarounds available are as follows:
>
> 1. Select a version of the Windows 10 SDK that's fully installed on the system (i.e. 10.0.14393.0 or earlier) in the Project Properties
> 2. Install the 'Windows 10 SDK (10.0.15063.0) for Desktop' component via the Visual Studio Installer. win10sdk-15063desktop.png
>
> Daniel Griffing,
>
> Visual C++ Libraries

Comment: Thanks. That's all I need for an explanation to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, honestly, looks like a bug in VS 2017. Just switch to `10.0.10586.0`.