# kernel32.lib error while building VS2013 project on Cmake in windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmake, windows-10

I'm working on windows 10 and I want to build the CLAPACK library for VS2013 using CMake.
Now I'm getting error in linking kernel32.lib.
I used to get this error inside Visual Studio during the building process, but I've solved it by including "D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.15063.0\um\x64" in the additional libraries section.
I've also tried to uninstall the SDK and reinstall it, with no hope.

Is there anyway to manually include the library directory in the building process in Cmake, or any other way to fix this error?

**EDIT #1:**
quoted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422105/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib-when-windows-sdk-version-is-set-to-15)

> The Windows 10 Creators Update SDK made some significant changes to
> what is installed as part of the installation to minimize on-disk
> footprint. This is a Known Issue that results from that refactoring
> work where the "desktop" components of the Creators Update SDK do not
> get installed by default.

EDIT #2:
could it be a compatibility issue between VS 2013 and windows 10?
my SDK version is 10.0.15063 which needs desktop components to be added manually, my problem is I don't know how to solve this for the VS as whole not a specific project.

Comment: You shouldn't need to include such system directories inside your CMake configuration. It should be part of your development environment. Are you using the Visual Studio Command Prompts? You could create a batch file that adds the library to the environment too.

Comment: I'm using the Cmake GUI, and the original error is "No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found" but inside the error log file the building stops when it reaches the step of creating  a VS project, that's why I think it's related to VS itself.
I found some useful information and updated my answer based on them, but still unable to solve the issue

Comment: What generator are you using?

Comment: Did you run ````"%vs120comntools%../../vc/vcvarsall.bat" Amd64```` before running cmake?

Comment: @arrowd I'm using Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64

Comment: @Knitschi should I run this from the original cmd? or the VS cmd? 
I ran it through the original one -because I found no cmd for VS 2013 om my pc, there's only a VS 2012 cmd- but I got no results and the problem still there!

Comment: @Knitschi I searched inside the directory you mentioned and found no vcvarscall.bat file, the only thing I found is vsvars32.bat

Comment: Are you sure? The directory should be something like this ````C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC>```` depending on where you installed Visual Studio 13.

Comment: The plain cmd. ````vcvarsall.bat```` will set some environment variables that will point the vc compiler to the right libraries and include directories etc. The visual studio command line has these variables already set. So you should not need to call vcvarsall.bat in that case. Also I am not sure if you want to compile 64 bit or 32 bit. The ````Amd64```` option is only needed when compiling for 64bit. If that is the case, also make sure that you use cmake with the generator option ````-G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"````

Comment: Also I am not sure if the wrong environment is what causes your problem. If the environment is wrong you usually get errors during the cmake ````project()```` call when cmake does the compiler tests.